# how to set a file's lastModifiedDate?

Tags: android, file, filesystems

For my app I want to keep track of which files have been accessed most recently (for cache management: files used least are first to go out).

Now Android doesn't appear to have a last accessed date function for files, so I'm looking at the next best thing: file.lastModifiedDate(). That gives me the last modified date, which is effectively the creation date.

But when accessing the file I'd like to set this value to the current time. Like Linux's touch command. How can I do this, without actually modifying the file?

Comment: Have you thought about using your own wrapper class that has this functionality as a private field with getters/setters?  Perhaps you can have an interface defining your contract, to keep the coupling loose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

http://www.java-examples.com/set-last-modified-time-file-or-directory

Comment: The key command in which is simply file.setLastModified(long). Right... makes me wonder why that didn't turn up in my google searches! Thanks.

Comment: file.setLastModified(long) would not work for all devices. Make sure the return status of setLastModified is checked before taking necessary action.